# Get the number of friends a facebook user has

Tags: python, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have 2 unrelated questions.

1. How many posts does facebook allow you to get with an api?
2. Using facepy, facebook, or any other api, how do I get the number of friends a user has? (This user is not my friend). The user id is provided.

This is how I currently get the number of my friends with facebook api:

```
>>> from facebook import *
>>> token = 'whatevertheinfo'
>>> graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
>>> friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
>>> len(friends['data'])
1
```

If I try `>>> friends = graph.get_connections("100000549223625", "friends")` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#55>", line 1, in <module>
    friends = graph.get_connections("100000549223625", "friends")
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\visolank\Desktop\Python\programs\facebook.py", line 112, in get_connections
    return self.request(id + "/" + connection_name, args)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\visolank\Desktop\Python\programs\facebook.py", line 298, in request
    raise GraphAPIError(response)
GraphAPIError: Unsupported operation
```

I dont need to know who the friends are, I just need a number. I know it's possible, because facebook claims:

"Public Profile and Friend List

The public profile and friend list is the basic information available to an app. All other permissions and content must be explicitly asked for."

Comment: If you have 2 unrelated questions, ask 2 separate questions. The [ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), can be used multiple times without penalty. *(note the singular use of question)* Clear questions will improve your chances of clear answers (and upvotes, if you care for reputation).

Answer (score 9):

This is intentional behaviour. There was a [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/356511554434996) filed for this problem, and this was the official Facebook response:

> This is intentional, you cannot retrieve friends lists for non-users of the app.

I suspect that if you used a userid of someone that had installed your app it might work, but not just any arbitrary user.

Answer (score 3):

**answer to question 1 (How many posts does facebook allow you to get with an api call):**

When querying facebook through FQL (facebook query language), you can limit the result up to 5000 records. So I'd say 5000.

**answer to question 2 (how do I get the number of friends a user has):**

You can query all the friends of the currently logged in user. You cannot however, ask facebook for the number of friends of a user that's not logged in through your app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get access/token from the user you are trying to get the friends list

Answer (score 0):

Use [python sdk for facebook graph api](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fb/0.3.0). This should work. Read the ***fetch objects from facebook*** part and then it should be really easy.

Just to help you.

import fb
facebook=fb.graph.api(token)
friends=facebook.get_object(cat='single', id='the_user_id', fields=["friends"] )

Now friends will have a python dictionary containing the user's friends.